# JMicro Ethernet Card Error 10

Tags: windows-7, linux, bios, ethernet

I have an ASUS K52JR notebook, Windows 7 / X64. Everything was fine, but sometimes the Windows crashed (blue screen). Then I made a BIOS update on the machine.

Because I used WiFi and mobile stick in many places, I never realized there was a problem. But yesterday I saw that JMicron Ethernet Card (251?) showed an error code 10.

I tried everything. I updated the driver, got JMicron directly, everything, but it showed error code 10, and never started. I have the latest BIOS now. The crashes are vanished, but I don't have `eth0`.

I tried with Ubuntu. I also cannot up `eth0`, it shows `ffffffff` for hw address. I checked the system log and it is shown that error is started *after* the BIOS update.

So I'm confused now: Is this a BIOS problem or isn't it?

As I know is that Linux ignores the BIOS, and tries to directly use the devices. If it is true then this is HW problem. But it's strange that the problems started on exactly same date when I updated the BIOS.

What do you think?

Comment: My guess is that the BIOS update may have caused the issue, have you tried rolling back to the previous BIOS update?

Comment: I used WinFlash to do BIOS update. But I don't found any option to rollback to update, or do update with older BIOS. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This was a motherboard problem. The service replaced it with a well working new motherboard.